# Question of Degrees of freedom negative in SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, degrees-of-freedom

I have a "F_A_T_A_L  E_R_R_O_R: Degrees of freedom is negative.", what can be the solution?

Comment: You have too many parameters. DF = number of moments (typically variances + covariances) - number of parameters. Often this means you've done something like left a whole bunch of means or covariances unconstrained.